# Import could not be resolved, the module is user built, but the code runs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

I have a directory and the structure of two files is below

```
python/solver-tic-tac-toe.py
python/players.py
```

I have this for my import statement in `solver-tic-tac-toe.py`

```
import players
```

But I get from VSCode

```
Import "players" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

However the code still runs as expected. What is the problem and how do I fix it?

*updated
I added an empty `__init__.py` file to the directory so that there is a Python package

Comment: Please try creating an empty __init__.py file in the "python" directory. This will make the directory a Python package. Reload your VSCode window for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

##### Add the following settings in *settings.json*:

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "path\to\python\folder"
    ],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "path\to\python\folder"
    ]
```

*Use absolute path if relative path are invalid.*